# XSLT did not work with docbook xmlns

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, docbook, docbook-5

I am totally new with xslt and try to make simple XSLT for converting docbook5 to [fb2/fb3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FictionBook) and other formats needed for me.
But I found problem that I can not understand - if `<book>` tag has `xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"` xslt did not work.
Minimal example of docbook (db.docbook):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <book xml:id="simple_book" version="5.0"
    xml:lang="ru"
    xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 >
  <info>
   <title>An Example Book</title>
  </info>
 </book>
```

and XSLT (xsl/example.xsl):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <tag><xsl:value-of select="/book/info/title"/></tag>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I try xsltproc

```
xsltproc xsl/example.xsl db.docbook
```

and saxon

```
saxon-xslt db.docbook xsl/example.xsl
```

in Debian GNU/Linux 9.1, but got

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tag/>
```

if I remove xmlns in docbook:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <book xml:id="simple_book" version="5.0"
    xml:lang="ru"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 >
  <info>
   <title>An Example Book</title>
  </info>
 </book>
```

both processors make right output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tag>An Example Book</tag>
```

May be somebody know how make xslt without removing xlmns?

Comment: @JLRishe yes it is look like the same problem, but I can not say that question solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare the namespace in your XSLT and use it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <tag><xsl:value-of select="/db:book/db:info/db:title"/></tag>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's works, but add xmlns to output:
`<tag xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">An Example Book</tag>`
as i understood it is not what i need

Comment: @AlexeyShrub Use `exclude-result-prefixes` as shown in the other question.

Comment: @michael.hor257k thanks!